# I am not able to figure out what's the problem here

Tags: mysql, mariadb

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 9
SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `usersdb`.`users_details` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE)
```

Comment: What is your MySQL Version?

Comment: Visible indexes do not exists in mariadb 'Ignored indexes were added in MariaDB 10.6.
Ignored indexes are indexes that are visible and maintained, but which are not used by the optimizer. MySQL 8 has a similar feature which they call "invisible indexes".' You should also check the manual for ASC which I don't think is an option.

Comment: Also the `VISIBLE` indexes doesn't work on MySQL version 5.7 and below.

Comment: version 10.4.24 mariaDB

Comment: Check my previous comment , also are you using mysqlworkbenh?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL indices are visible by default, and prior to MySQL 8+, the `VISIBLE` and `INVISIBLE` keywords are not supported.  Assuming you are running 5.7 or earlier, try removing `VISIBLE`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE usersdb.users_details (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    email_address VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (id)
);
```

**Edit:** I just realized from your error output that you are using MariaDB.  The fix would be the same as above, but I am not sure at which exact version MariaDB rolled out invisible indices.